# VoiceOver reads labels on previous view in iPhone app? bug? 

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility, voiceover

I am creating view based application, where i will be going to next view, via `addSubview` method.
The problem is, when I turn the feature of VoiceOver ON, and addsubviews, it takes the accessory labels from previous views. That is , if I click on view at the rect, where there is label in previous view, then also, VoiceOver will detect it as accessibility label and start reading that label.
But, If I use, navigation controller to go to next view controller, I don't get any problem.
Can anyone please tell me, if apple itself has supported VoiceOver facility only for navigation based application, or there is some other solution for VoiceOver in view based applications ?

PS I have tried the same on some demo apps also, but same results.

So, when in current view I am adding a subview which contains buttons, accessibility reads the labels behind the subview as well. I want the accessibility to read buttons on added view, and rest of the viewable part of the previous view only(and not the labels got hidden behind added view).
can someone tell, if it is a bug of voiceover in iPhone, that by default, it reads parentView's labels also, on addsubview ?

Comment: Are your hidden labels placed within your view with the hidden check box selected, or have you imported them to the xib or storyboard, and they are only being stored on the side bar?

Comment: My labels are getting hidden behind the added view. I just elaborated it in my question now.
I am adding subview on a current view, which contains buttons, there are some labels behind this subview, and voiceover is reading those labels also, which is not supposed to happen.

Comment: No. I have created different views(containing labels, buttons,images), along with one main view in xib, and I add any one of the views to main view whenever required.

Comment: Your best bet will probably be to try releasing your labels in the method you call to load your subviews.

Comment: Releasing labels every time shall work, but then it will be real complicated, to manually remove each label which becomes invisible in view, and then again adding them when we need to show them.
I suppose, there shall be some solution to stop voiceover from reading labels on back view (After addSubView)?
 Because, even when I am adding subView of another viewController, voiceover reads labels from previous view, is it the bug in voiceover ?

Comment: VoiceOver is reading label of previous page instead of current page in Angular 2, help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this screen changed notification

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, nil);
```

if you need to focus a specific object/view then pass those at the place of nil.

Comment: where do we need to add this line?

Comment: only exact the same line or we need to change something?

Comment: Yes, that will inform accessibility that user has changed the screen so that it will not consider the previous screen.

Comment: Has changed to `UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: nil)` in recent versions of iOS

Answer (score 9):

If a view is in the view hierarchy, even if it is obscured by another view on top of it, VoiceOver will detect that.

You should not be moving to another screen of content by just adding a new view on top of the previous one. Each screen of your app should be a `UIViewController`, not just a plain `UIView`. This gives you many advantages, one of which is that a view controller can automatically unload its view when it is off screen and there is a memory warning.

To manage transitions between screens in your app, you should use a container controller like a navigation controller (or your own custom one). You can disable the navigation bar and transition effects if you like, and just use it to manage your stack of views. When you push a new view controller onto the stack, the previous one will be removed and your problem goes away.

So you should seriously reconsider the way you are managing your screens and views. `UIViewController` inside some sort of container is the way to go. At the very least, you should be removing the old view when you add a new one to the screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587155/voiceover-access-previous-screen-element any idea?

Answer (score 6):

You can set the accessibilityViewIsModal property of the view to YES.

> @property (nonatomic) BOOL accessibilityViewIsModal NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
>
> Informs whether the receiving view should be considered modal by accessibility. If YES, then
> elements outside this view will be ignored. Only elements inside this view will be exposed.
> default == NO

so whatever view you are adding, set it's accessibilityViewIsModal to YES / true.

`view.accessibilityViewIsModal = YES`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you, and I spent some time to solve this.
When you add view B over view A, you do not hidden view A. The view continues there, and as expected by voiceOver, it will read that view/label.

You can use the Debug View that Xcode provides for you, to see this kind of problem. I wrote a example to demostre you how voiceOver see your labels.

When you use addSubview, you hierarchy of views are like that:

[image: overview]

So in this case, the container view, with Hello Stack! label is over the Hello World label. As a user you cannot see the label Hello World. However voiceOver can see that view.

All right, now that the problem is known, the solution is: whenever you want to add a view over another one, first hidden the previous view. Then use Debug View of xcode to see how your views are.

I fix that to show you how to correct the error I demonstrated:

In Code:
[image]

Debug view:

- first label: postimg.org/image/cabhadzrl/
- second label: postimg.org/image/nsldgjb41/5605fbcd/

If you observer, I had added a view container between the labels, but this view is just to improve the vision of the hierarchy.

Comment: I like your go getter attitude but I want to use a modal view.  So I wouldn't want my views behind to become transparent.